# How to scroll two divs vertically together in angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular8

I have two divs of same heights. They are placed inside a parent div horizontally one after another.

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="div1">
          <div *ngFor="let item of list;" style="height: 30px;">{{item.id}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
           <div *ngFor="let item of list;" style="height: 30px;">{{item.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The styles are like this

```
.div1{
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
}
.div2{
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   width: 500px;
   float: left;
}
```

The ts file has a function that sets the data in the `list` array

```
list = [];
setData() {
   for (let i = 0; i< 300; i ++) {
      this.list.push({id: i, value: `value is: ${i}`});
   }
}
```

Now what i want is when i scroll vertically inside one div (class name `div1` or `div2`), the other `div` should also scroll the same way. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**: div2 should be horizontally scrollable as well.

Comment: Hello can't you make the parent scrollable so they scroll together ?

Comment: Updated my question. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You an add a fixed `height` and `overflow: scroll` to the parent to scroll them together

```css
.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  background: aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">
    <h4>Div1</h4>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>

  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <h4>Div2</h4>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
    <div class="item">123</div>
  </div>
</div>
```